# Shipment Note PDF Print don't shows the shop address magento2

Tags: magento2, address

I am trying to put the store address to the shipment pdf. I found that Magento has an own function for address insertion, but it doesn't work.

```
Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php
   public function getPdf($shipments = [])
    {
...
 $this->insertAddress($page, $shipment->getStore());
```

Sales/Model/Order/AbstractPdf.php

```
protected function insertAddress(&$page, $store = null)
    {

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $font = $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setLineWidth(0);
        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = 815;
        foreach (explode(
                     "\n",
                     $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                         'sales/identity/address',
                         \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                         $store
                     )
                 ) as $value) {

            if ($value !== '') {

                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(
                        trim(strip_tags($_value)),
                        $this->getAlignRight($_value, 130, 440, $font, 10),
                        $top,
                        'UTF-8'
                    );
                    $top -= 10;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->y = $this->y > $top ? $top : $this->y;
    }
```